# HttpServletRequest: How to determine Content-Type of requested asset

Tags: java, jetty, content-type, servlets

I am writing a quick-and-dirty static file server using Jetty. I need to set the Content-Type for each response:

```
HttpServletResponse.setContentType("content/type");
```

For a given file request, how do I reliably determine what content type to set? Is it a question of examining the file extension, or is there a more sophisticated method? (E.g what if there is no file extension, or the extension does not reflect the content type?)

Thanks Richard

Comment: I know two solutions: - [javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html) from JavaBeans activation framework (seems available in Java SE 6 ?!) - [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) A [interesting tutorial](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html) about this subject with a lot of various solutions I didn't try.

Comment: You should look into this library. It does a lot of stuff (file extensions, magic data and content sniffing) to determine the content type: [Mime Type Detection Utility](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/)

Comment: Not sure if this fits your requirements, but I've recently released my [SimpleMagic](http://256.com/sources/simplemagic/) package which implements the same functionality as the Unix file(1) command. It uses either internal config files or can read `/etc/magic`, `/usr/share/file/magic`, or other magic(5) files and determine file content from `File`, `InputStream`, or `byte[]`. Location of the [github sources](https://github.com/j256/simplemagic), javadocs, and some documentation are available from the [home page](http://256.com/sources/simplemagic/). With SimpleMagic, you do something like the

Comment: SimpleMagic now is at: http://256stuff.com/sources/simplemagic/

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the HttpServletResponse object in your question, I'm assuming you have the ServletContext available to you in your Controllers. I just solved this same problem just using methods available from the servletContext.

Since you're writing a file server, you can just pass in the path to the file in the getMimeType method of the ServletContext, and it should return the mimeType, if it can determine it.

```
String path = "/js/example.js";
String mimeType = getServletContext().getMimeType(path);
resp.setContentType(mimeType);   // HttpServletResponse object
```

> NOTE: Sets the content type to "application-x/javascript" in this particular example.

**Additional information:**  I believe this solution also assumes your files are stored in a location accessible to the ServletContext. If not, then one of the other solutions may be best.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just check the request header `Content-Type` and set the response to that?

I don't know the kind of clients you are planning to support but if they are browsers I guess you should be fine with that. If you control the clients, it's a good practice that they send you that header anyways.

Good Luck!

Comment: The client's I am supporting are browsers only. This is interesting suggestion, I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream(java.io.InputStream))

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
```