# How to determine Content Type of a HTTP Servlet Request?

Tags: json, servlets, httprequest, content-type, http-request

How can I get the content type from the `HttpServletRequest` without reading the request body?

When I use the following, I get `null`:

```
request.getContentType()
```

When I try to read the JSON data that comes in the request body using the following:

```
StringBuilder jsonsb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader jsonbr = request.getReader();
```

The `request.getReader()` throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:106)
```

I even tried using the following and was able to get the content type but, still getting the same `NullPointerException` while getting the reader from request after this statement.

```
request.getHeader("Accept")
```

Comment: your request object is null ...hence it throws nullpointerexception at the time of calling getreader() method

Comment: and possibly the case of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433844/httpservletrequest-how-to-determine-content-type-of-requested-asset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you handling a GET request. That might not contain a Content-Types header and therefore you are seeing a null there.

Comment: i just noticed that , this was happening only for GET request. So how can i get the ContentType for GET requests ? There are few scenarios the GET request sends the parameters as JSON string, rather than query string. I want to differentiate between these 2 scenarios.