# How to read JSON content (in Servlet Filter) sent via GET method?

Tags: json, servlets, http-post, content-type, http-get

In follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049094/how-to-determine-content-type-of-a-http-servlet-request/30049965#30049965) , my GET request is returning a 'application/json' content type.

***I want this JSON content as a String, so that i can use the Jackson Library to validate if this is a properly constructed JSON or not. Is there any other way i can read this content apart from request.getParameter() ?***

Note: For a POST request, i used request.getReader() to get the JSON content. But this doesn't work for a GET request.

Comment: What exactly are you talking about? You are trying to read the response to a GET request? If yes, how? If no, there's no "body" in a get request. All that you can read are the path params and query params.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it. The spring controller was using @ResponseBody to map the incoming params into a POJO and along with ResponseBody annotation, there were some more configurations saying the incoming is going to be json content type. In fact, when i did a request.getContentType it gave application/json as content type.